# jquery ajax 422 coming in as a success in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, jquery-forms-plugin

I've got a site that's using rails3, jquery-forms, and I'm testing in firefox and chome.

For the sake of testing, I've got the server returning 422 status every time.

When I submit my form, Firefox correctly hits "error." Chrome incorrectly hits "success."

Anyone have any ideas why this might be the case?

```
$('form').ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        console.log("It hits success");         
    },
    error: function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
            console.log("It hits failure");
    }
    });
```

Comment: What does your action looks like, do you render response as json?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your server code looks like this :

```
def update
 @model = Model.find(params[:id])
 @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
 if @model.save
   render :json => @model, :status => :ok
 else
   head :unprocessable_entity # aka 422 status code
 end
end
```

So first of all, is there any file upload involved in your ajax request? Apparently, the HTTP status code cannot be used in that case. [topic on JQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-form-does-not-care-about-status-code-for-success-or-error-callback)

Conditions for a success callback is a 2xx status or 304 (not modified).